# Google Ads Scripts - Send Logger.log content to email?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, scripting, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I have a script that shows 10 most clicked keywords, their average CPC and conversions. While previewing the script it works fine. But when I send it to my email, only last row of the 10 rows shows. What is wrong here?

```js
function main() {
  var keywords = AdsApp.keywords()
      .orderBy("Clicks DESC")
  //  .orderBy("Impressions DESC")
      .forDateRange("THIS_MONTH")
      .withLimit(10)
      .get();

Logger.log("10 most clicked keywords");
  while (keywords.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = keywords.next();
    content = keyword.getText() + " | Clicks: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getClicks() + " | CPC: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getAverageCpc().toFixed(2) + 
    " | Conversions: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getConversions();
  }
  
MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: 'myemail@myemail.com',
            subject: "10 most clicked keywords",
            htmlBody: content
});  
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're over-writing the content variable with every while loop. I think you need to declare content outside the while loop and then add it to your content = string e.g.

```
var content = "";      
while (keywords.hasNext()) {
        var keyword = keywords.next();
        content = content + keyword.getText() + " | Clicks: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getClicks() + " | CPC: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getAverageCpc().toFixed(2) + 
        " | Conversions: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getConversions();
      }
```

I suspect you'll probably want to add a new line character  `+ "\n"` at the end of the concatenations as well.

Comment: Hey, this almost worked! But for some reason it shows 9 results, leaving the most clicked keyword out, do you have any idea why?

Comment: So basically the 1st result seems to be overwritten by the others, for some reason.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure. Suppose we should make sure the first term is actually processed by the while loop (although it appears identical to the script in the guide). Have you added `Logger.log(keyword);` on the line after `var keyword...` to make sure it's definitely processing the first keyword?

Comment: While you're at it, add `Logger.log(content);` to the line after content too so we can double check if it's actually getting written to the content string at all.

Comment: No unfortunately it didn't solve it :/ I added the things you mentioned but nothing changed.

Comment: It won't fix anything but do you definitely see the missing result in the logs?

Comment: Logger.log("Top 10 keywords");
  while (keywords.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = keywords.next();
    Logger.log(keyword);
    var content = "";
    Logger.log(content);
    while (keywords.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = keywords.next();
    content = content + keyword.getText() + " | Clicks: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getClicks() + " | CPC: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getAverageCpc().toFixed(2) + 
    " | Conversions: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getConversions() + "<br>";
    }

Comment: To be honest no, it just shows me some random stuff, starting like this {bidding=function () {...}, getCampaign=function () {...},.....

Comment: My apologies. I wasn't clear enough with where to put the Logger commands. Try this: `Logger.log("Top 10 keywords"); var content = ""; while (keywords.hasNext()) { var keyword = keywords.next(); Logger.log(keyword); content = content + keyword.getText() + " | Clicks: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getClicks() + " | CPC: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getAverageCpc().toFixed(2) + " | Conversions: " + keyword.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH").getConversions() + "<br>";  Logger.log(content); }`

Comment: I've just edited my edit. The code you copied called `while (keywords.hasNext()) { var keyword = keywords.next();` twice, so the first time it pulled your first keyword from the list, and then you called a second while loop and over-wrote the keyword variable with the second keyword.

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping me. I applied your solution and it seems 1st keyword isnt being processed for some reason.

Comment: Now it works, thank you so much for helping me out!